# How to solve "Cookies disabled the application requires cookies to function" produced by Vaadin FLOW (14+) on Tomcat with SSL?

Tags: cookies, apache2, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I deployed an application (usual Apache-tomcat bridge) and I am getting this message:

[image]

But cookies are enabled! I read [this post](https://mvysny.github.io/the-dreaded-vaadin-session-has-expired/) but it is none of those causes. Anyway, I also commented out the Push and PWA directives - just in case. The issue persists.

Without SSL (Pure tomcat on port 8080) I do not get this message.

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: I have links to two posts to check, other is about Apache config https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/3620992 and the other about Tomcat config https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18124830/issue-in-vaadin-while-using-in-embeded

Comment: Do you see this message in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, it happens in all browsers (Chrome, Brave, and Firefox). I already added the CookieProcessor directive to tomcat conf/context.xml, but I got the same result. I didn't try the proxy pass reverse on cookies because the post refers to Vaadin 7.

Comment: Last attempt with proxy pass also failed:         ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/everylunch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/everylunch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain/
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath http://127.0.0.1:8080/everylunch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain/ /

Comment: Update: I wrote a small application using Thymeleaf instead of Vaadin, only to test reading/writing cookies, and deployed it on the same server. The Thymeleaf application correctly reads and writes cookies, the issue is surely related to Vaadin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I tried to redirect Apache2 to the root and use the full path of the application and Vaadin stopped complaining. I deduced there was a path problem in the cookies and I added to my Apache2 SSL configuration:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /my-App-Path /
```

And Vaadin stopped complaining.